# Trouble with SQL join, where, having clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, logging

I'm having trouble understanding how to make a query that will show me 'the three most popular articles' in terms of views ('Status: 200 OK').

There are 2 tables I'm currently dealing with.

1. A Log table
2. An Articles table

The columns in these tables: 
                                  Table "public.log"

```
 Column |           Type           |                    Modifiers                     
--------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 path   | text                     | 
 ip     | inet                     | 
 method | text                     | 
 status | text                     | 
 time   | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 id     | integer                  | not null default nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Indexes:

and

```
                             Table "public.articles"

 Column |           Type           |                       Modifiers                       
--------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 author | integer                  | not null
 title  | text                     | not null
 slug   | text                     | not null
 lead   | text                     | 
 body   | text                     | 
 time   | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 id     | integer                  | not null default nextval('articles_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Indexes:

.

So far, I've written this query based on my level and current understanding of SQL...

```
SELECT articles.title, log.status 
FROM articles join log
WHERE articles.title = log.path
HAVING status = “200 OK”
GROUP BY title, status
```

Obviously, this is incorrect. I want to be able to pull the three most popular articles from the database and I know that 'matching' the 200 OK's with the "article title" will show or count in for me one "view" or hit. My thought process is like, I need to determine how many times that article.title=log.path (1 unique) shows up in the log database (with a status of 200 OK) by creating a query. My assignment is actually to write a program that will print the results with "[my code getting] the database to do the heavy lifting by using joins, aggregations, and the where clause.. doing minimal "post-processing" in the Python code itself."

Any explanation, idea, a tip is appreciated all of StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following is what you have in mind:

```
SELECT
    a.title,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN log l
   ON a.title = l.path
WHERE
    l.lstatus = '200 OK'
GROUP BY
    a.title
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This would return the three article titles having the highest status 200 hit counts.  This answer assumes that you are using MySQL.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Why do we abbreviate ‘a.title’ and ‘l.path’? I’ve once seen a query written with two unique identifiers written before the column name using select but I’m not sure what is selected when doing that.. example: a.id, b.id and there is only one column in the table that is named “Id”..

Comment: @purpleorbiter63 This is actually a fairly long question.  Short answer, in the outer select, you may select two columns both of which are called `id`.  But in a subquery, this is not possible, and you should instead distinguish one from the other, e.g. use `id_a` and `id_b`.

Comment: Ok, I've tried the code and it doesn't work for me. I'm still stuck. I'm trying to achieve something like.. `Select title, name, num from articles join authors on articles.author = authors.id join log on authors.id = log.id; 
` because I want to have a column displaying the number of views that each individual article would actually have

Comment: Perhaps just adding `COUNT(*)` to the select clause is what you want?  Check my updated answer.